# If a function is bounded on a set does this mean ut is constant?

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, upper-lower-bounds

> Let $H$ be the upper half plane and let $S$ be the union
>   of the first and third quadrants.
>
> (a) Suppose that an entire function $f$ is bounded on $H$. Does it follow that $f$ is constant?
>
> (b) Suppose that an entire function f is bounded on $S$. Does it follow that $f$ is constant?

My attempts:

a) $H$={$x+iy : x \in (-∞,∞),y \in (0,∞)$}

$f$ is bounded on $H$, then there exists a constant $M$ such that for all $z \in H$, $|f(z)| ≤ M$, hence $-M ≤ f(z) ≤ M$.

Let $z_0 \in H$ and so $0≤f(z_0+h)-f(z_0)≤0$

Then lim$_{h → 0} \frac{f(z_0 + h) - f(z_0)}{h}$ = lim$_{h → 0}  0 = 0 = f'(z_0)$ (by squeeze theorem)

So since the derivative is equal to zero ($f'(z) =0$), the function is constant.

b) $S$ = {$x+iy : x\in (-∞,∞), y \in (-∞,∞)$}

And since $f$ is bounded on $S$, then there exists $M$ for all $z \in S$ such that $|f(z)|≤ M$

But isn't this the same as part a)? What's the difference. Please correct me if I'm mistaken on the answerr.

Comment: For part (a), how does it follows that $z_0 \in H \implies 0\leq f(z_0+h)-f(z_0)\leq 0$? If this were the case, that would imply $f(z_0+h)=f(z_0)$ for all arbitrary $z_0$ and $h$. Hence, you are assuming what you are trying to prove.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$e^{iz}$ is bounded by $1$ in the upper half-plane and it is nonconstant; $e^{iz^2}$ is bounded by $1$ when $xy \ge 0$ hence in the set $S$

As asked:

$|e^{i(x+iy)}|=e^{-y} \le 1$ when $y \ge 0$

$|e^{i(x+iy)^2}|=|e^{i(x^2-y^2+2ixy)}|=e^{-2xy} \le 1$ when $xy \ge 0$

Comment: Can you please explain more?

Comment: edited as asked

Comment: I'm not sure words like "trivially" and "manifestly" help.

Comment: @zhw - removed them, no problem

Comment: @Conrad so is $e^{(iz^2)}$ a constant function on $S$?

Comment: No it is not constant on $S$; entire functions can be bounded on large parts of the plane (half plane, two quadrants etc) without being constant

Answer (score 1):

Hint: $\exp(iz)$ is bounded on the upper half plane.